# Is this the reason why acceleration isn't change in velocity per unit distance?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, velocity

I believe that the reason acceleration isn't measured as change in per unit distance but instead is measured as change in per unit time is because of the following reason :

Time is not geometrical. It either increases or decreases constantly and can be considered like a straight line. But whereas distance is similar to this but only when it is literally a straight line. But distance need not be like this all the time.

For example : If we were measuring change in velocity of an object per unit distance and per unit time, where the object is traveling in a straight line, the acceleration for the former and latter would probably be different values but that's fine. But if we were doing the same for an object traveling in a circle, it would cause issues as things start to become complex when using distance.

I believe this is correct. Is there something wrong with this explanation or is the reason for not using distance completely different? Also, are there more reasons for not using distance? If so, what are they?

I apologize if this question seems to casual/dumb.

Comment: Acceleration is DEFINED as change in velocity with respect to time.  Change in velocity with respect to distance is a different variable.

Comment: @DavidWhite I think the question is: why do we define it that way? Why is the second time derivative of position the important quantity, rather than something else?

Comment: Ik. What I meant by my question is that, is the reason for not defining acceleration as change in velocity per unit distance the same reason as mine?

Comment: If you take acceleration to be change in velocity per unit distance that would define velocity as distance per unit distance and would give different results for the same velocity.

Comment: Acceleration is the *rate of change* of velocity, by definition. A gradient like $\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x}$ would only have use in very limited cases.

Comment: Note: When you're pondering the answers, you may want to keep in mind that the velocity of a particle is defined as the [first derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of its position with respect to time, and its acceleration is defined as the [second derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative) of its position with respect to time. Also note, that time is a _scalar_ quantity while position, velocity, and acceleration all are _vector_ quantities.

Comment: There is only **one** true independent quantity in this universe, and that is _proper time_. Everything else is dependent on proper time.

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{d\vec v}{ds}$ isn't as well-behaved (and so not as useful) as $\frac{d\vec v}{dt}$.
This can be seen as follows:$$\frac{d\vec v}{ds}=\frac{d\vec v}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}.$$
So,
$$\frac{d\vec v}{ds}=\frac1v\frac{d\vec v}{dt}.$$
in which $v$ is the body's speed.

We see that $\frac{d\vec v}{ds}$ is undefined when the body is at rest and not accelerating (in the ordinary sense) and infinite if it is at rest but accelerating (like a pendulum bob at the end of its swing).

Comment: I think this is the best answer, since it clearly shows how useless the alternative definition of acceleration is when the body is stationary.

Comment: I was gonna write this and then work tore me away from the question! The only thing I would have added to this is that this derivative is, at least in one dimension, the total time derivative of $\log (v/v_0)$ and so it in some sense amounts to a redefinition of velocity as well; it makes sense precisely when the velocity is exponential in some sort of “rapidity” (but not the relativistic one) that you would “prefer” to be analyzing instead.

Answer (score 3):

Change in velocity with respect to time has the useful property that its value stays the same when you switch to a coordinate system that is in constant motion, relative to the original one. Change in velocity with respect to distance does not. It's just acceleration (as we know it) divided by the magnitude of the velocity in the local coordinate system.

Comment: This is the answer. Change in speed per unit distance constantly changes since speed affects distance traveled so the numerator affects the denominator. You end up with a number that is always changing which is difficult to work with. If I say the object started from 0m/s and increased in velocity by 1m/s every meter traveled that number would have changed the very next instant when the speed was different, let alone waiting until the object actually traveled one meter.

Comment: This is a very good answer, indeed. So the claim is (1) Everybody in classical mechanics agrees on *changes* in velocity even if they do not agree on actual velocities; (2) Everybody in classical mechanics agrees on the progress of time: therefore the only definition of a force which everyone agrees on would be as a disposition to change velocity per unit time. Per Philip Wood's answer, to redefine to be “per unit distance” would redefine $\vec F' = \vec F/\|\vec v\|$ and now what “force” you measure depends on what reference frame you inhabit, subsuming Fritsch's answer. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

We know (since [Galileo's experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei#Falling_bodies) around 1600) that the velocity
of a free falling body constantly increases by $9.8$ m/s every *second*.
Therefore it makes sense to *define* acceleration as the
change of velocity per *time*.
Then the movement of *all* bodies falling free near the earth
can be fully described by just one and the same constant number.
Of course this is a great simplification in describing falling bodies.

There are other physical scenarios (e.g. pushing/pulling a mass across
a frictionless surface with constant force)
where the result is again a constant acceleration.
Hence, this definition of acceleration is also useful there.

On the other hand: I don't know any physical scenario
where the change of velocity per *distance* would be constant.
Using this so-defined quantity would not enable you to describe
any physical situation in an easier way than without using this quantity.